# Impresión de etiquetas en impresoratermica

Tags: genexus

No consigo imprimir en la impresora de etiquetas des de un procedimiento.
Si puedo crear un pdf, pero lo que quiero es imprimir directametne ese pdf a impresora.

He configurado el Procedimiento los valores:

"Main Program" en ture

"Call Protocol" a HTTP

"Report output en Only to printer.

En las reglas, he añadido estas:

```
output_file('ETIQ.pdf','pdf');
printer("ETIQ");
```

El archivo GXPRN.ini, esel siguiente:

```
[General_Config_info]
Version=3
XOffset=0
YOffset=0
CheckPaperSize=0
[ETIQUETES]
Printer=QL-1060N
Mode=0
Orientation=1
PaperSize=1
PaperLength=1100
PaperWidth=550
Scale=100
Copies=0
DefaultSource=15
PrintQuality=600
Color=1
Duplex=1
XOffset=0
YOffset=0
```

Tambien he probado l oque pone en este enlace:
https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?36689,Impresi%C3%B3n+directa+Genexus+15+en+Firefox+y+en+Chrome

Y nada, no funciona nada oa casi nada, no puedo definir medidas de los margenes de impresión, no puedo seleccionar la impresora por la que va a salir la impresión, aún poniendo el nombre en el GXPRN.ini

Por favor, alguien me puede dar un poco de luz, o al final tendré que imprimir con ZPL?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score -2):

Existe un nuevo mecanismo de impresión directa, puede verificar el sac relacionado en el link https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=44949;;

Y la documentacion en este enlace https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?33912,Web+printing+on+client+printer+%28without+an+applet%29

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).